# Typescript find in array with different types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects, each object has different type.
I am using Array.find (or for loop, no difference) to get one of the objects from array. Right now Typescript can not understand what type i am getting from array unless i add additional `|| reportData.type !== "REGIONS"` check. Is there any other way to solve it?

```
 export interface IReportItemFactionStatus {
    type: "FACTION_STATUS";
  }

  export interface IReportItemRegions {
    type: "REGIONS";
    regions: [];
  }

  export type IReportItem = IReportItemRegions | IReportItemFactionStatus;

  export type IReport = Array<IReportItem>;

  // ... code ...
  // report has type IReport

  const reportData = report.find((d) => {
      return d.type === "REGIONS";
  });

  if (!reportData) {
    return [];
  }
  console.log(reportData.regions); // Typescript error here
```

But if i add additional check for reportData.type it starts to work fine

```
  if (!reportData || reportData.type !== "REGIONS") {
    return [];
  }
  console.log(reportData.regions); // No Typescript error here :\
```

Answer (score 1):

Your structure enforces `reportData` to be of type `IReportItem` which is :  `IReportItemRegions` or `IReportItemFactionStatus` because it's an element of `report` array.

You want to display property `regions` which is only implemented in interface `IReportItemRegions`. We have no idea if `reportData` is of type `IReportItemRegions`. Before trying to access the property, you must ensure your object implements the property :

```
if ('regions' in reportData) {
  console.log(reportData.regions)
}
```

If you want TypeScript to infer the type, you must get rid of `find` et rewrite your code. I've come with a simple implementation :

```
let reportData: IReportItemRegions;
let i = 0;
while (!reportData && report.length < i) {
  const currentReportData = report[i];
  if (currentReportData.type === 'REGIONS') {
    // Typescrit knows currentReportData is of type IReportItemRegions
    reportData = currentReportData;
  }
  i++;
}

if (!reportData) {
  return [];
}
console.log(reportData.regions);
```

Comment: It does not work. Type `IReportItem` is not assignable to type `IReportItemRegions`. Property `regions` is missing at IReportItemFactionStatus.

---


It looks weird for me that explicit check `|| reportData.type !== "REGIONS"` solves this but `type === "REGION"` in `IF` statement or `find` does not.

Comment: @ArtyomTrityak hmm, weird, the code I tested worked without compile time error. When you do an explicit check you narrow the variable to its specific type, that's why it's working. Here is some interesting documentation : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: `if ('regions' in reportData) {` check is check i want to avoid. If i can tell TS that this is type X it should already know this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
interface IReportItemFactionStatus {
  type: "FACTION_STATUS";
}

interface IReportItemRegions {
  type: "REGIONS";
  regions: readonly string[];
}

type IReportItem = IReportItemRegions | IReportItemFactionStatus;

const report = [
  {
    type: "REGIONS",
    regions: ["region"]
  },
  {
    type: "FACTION_STATUS"
  }
] as const satisfies readonly IReportItem[]

type LookUp<T, TType> = Extract<T, { type: TType }>;

function lookup<TArr extends readonly any[], const TType extends TArr[number]['type']>(arr: TArr, type: TType) {
  return arr.filter((d): d is LookUp<TArr[number], TType> => {
    return d.type === type;
  });
}

const x = lookup(report, "REGIONS")
// {
//     readonly type: "REGIONS";
//     readonly regions: readonly ["region"];
// }[]

const y = lookup(report, "FACTION_STATUS")
//  {
//     readonly type: "FACTION_STATUS";
// }[]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

TS throws error as the return value will be of type `IReportItemRegions | IReportItemFactionStatus`.

If its of type `IReportItemFactionStatus`, as there is no `regions` in it. So its should throw an error.

When you add this check: `reportData.type !== "REGIONS"`, you are telling typescript that for cases when you get `IReportItemFactionStatus`, you are returning before and `console.log(reportData.regions);` becomes unreachable code. Hence no error.

---

**Alternate way:**

```js
enum ReportType {
  REGIONS = "REGIONS",
  FACTION_STATUS = "FACTION_STATUS"
}

export interface IReportItem {
  type: ReportType;
  regions?: [];
}

// No need for this now
//export type IReportItem = IReportItemRegions | IReportItemFactionStatus;

export type IReport = Array < IReportItem > ;

// ... code ...
// report has type IReport

const reportData: IReportItem | null = report.find((d) => {
  return d.type === ReportType.REGION;
});

if (!reportData) {
  return [];
}
console.log(reportData.regions); // Typescript error here
```

Comment: Is it possible to tell Typescript that `report.find` returns IReportItemRegions type?

Comment: Just added a alternate option. There are number of options but in my understanding, this is the cleanest

Comment: Sorry but your solution is not valid. Your code gives possibility that object with `FACTION_STATUS` type (`type="FACTION_STATUS"`) will have regions. It is not possible. I have specific object types with fixed structure. And i need to make sure that object with such type has correct fields ie object with type "REGIONS" MUST have `regions: []`

Comment: `type="FACTION_STATUS"` is dealing with value. TS is about defining the structure instead. Yes, it will allow a possibility, but it will give you a warning that value may possibly be undefined for all values. So you have to deliberately say that value will be here. Nonetheless, I understand, you cannot use my approach. I'll still leave the answer in a hope it might help someone.

Comment: I think values are fine for Typescript, more reading here: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/03/typescript-2-0-tagged-union-types